# 'Antidotes have been since then introduced.' Is this correct word order?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> 'Antidotes have been since then introduced.'

It's possible to rephrase it as: 'Since then, antidotes have been introduced.', but I'm not sure if the first version is correct.

Comment: There are perhaps a half-dozen orderings that would be more idiomatic than yours.  "Antidotes have been introduced since then."  "Antidotes have, since then, been introduced."

Comment: Between the auxiliary and the main verb one can use many one-word adverbs, like _recently_ (_Antidotes have recently been introduced_), but you can't put a whole phrase like _since then_ in that niche.

Answer (score 1):

Since then, antidotes have been introduced.

The "since then" portion is out of sequence in the original, but there are myriad other ways to phrase this, i.e. Antidotes have been introduced since then, or, as in one of the comments above, Antidotes have, since then, been introduced, are only two more of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with this:
Antidotes have been, since then, introduced.
It's the same sentence with commas, because they're helpful, introduced.